# Syntax Error jQuery v3.1.1 "el.querySelectorAll("*,:x");" //line 1317

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Al momento de abrir la consola y recargar la página me envía directamente al depurador y me muestra en rojo la línea 1317 y queda cargando hasta cerrar la consola.

No creo que el problema esté en jQuery. No creo que sea el único que le ha pasado esto, ¿alguien sabe la solución?

Utilizo jQuery JavaScript Library v3.3.1:

```
        if ( el.querySelectorAll("[msallowcapture^='']").length ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push( "[*^$]=" + whitespace + "*(?:''|\"\")" );
        }

        // Support: IE8
        // Boolean attributes and "value" are not treated correctly
        if ( !el.querySelectorAll("[selected]").length ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push( "\\[" + whitespace + "*(?:value|" + booleans + ")" );
        }

        // Support: Chrome<29, Android<4.4, Safari<7.0+, iOS<7.0+, PhantomJS<1.9.8+
        if ( !el.querySelectorAll( "[id~=" + expando + "-]" ).length ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push("~=");
        }

        // Webkit/Opera - :checked should return selected option elements
        // http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#checked
        // IE8 throws error here and will not see later tests
        if ( !el.querySelectorAll(":checked").length ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push(":checked");
        }

        // Support: Safari 8+, iOS 8+
        // https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136851
        // In-page `selector#id sibling-combinator selector` fails
        if ( !el.querySelectorAll( "a#" + expando + "+*" ).length ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push(".#.+[+~]");
        }
    });

    assert(function( el ) {
        el.innerHTML = "<a href='' disabled='disabled'></a>" +
            "<select disabled='disabled'><option/></select>";

        // Support: Windows 8 Native Apps
        // The type and name attributes are restricted during .innerHTML assignment
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute( "type", "hidden" );
        el.appendChild( input ).setAttribute( "name", "D" );

        // Support: IE8
        // Enforce case-sensitivity of name attribute
        if ( el.querySelectorAll("[name=d]").length ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push( "name" + whitespace + "*[*^$|!~]?=" );
        }

        // FF 3.5 - :enabled/:disabled and hidden elements (hidden elements are still enabled)
        // IE8 throws error here and will not see later tests
        if ( el.querySelectorAll(":enabled").length !== 2 ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push( ":enabled", ":disabled" );
        }

        // Support: IE9-11+
        // IE's :disabled selector does not pick up the children of disabled fieldsets
        docElem.appendChild( el ).disabled = true;
        if ( el.querySelectorAll(":disabled").length !== 2 ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push( ":enabled", ":disabled" );
        }

        // Opera 10-11 does not throw on post-comma invalid pseudos
        el.querySelectorAll("*,:x");
        rbuggyQSA.push(",.*:");
    });
}
```

tomar_pedido.php esta es la pagina visible para el usuario

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- jQuery Plugins -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <!-- nouislider -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/nouislider.min.css"/>
    <!-- Slick -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css"/>

    <!-- Font Awesome Icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom stlylesheet -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

<?php
    session_start();
    include("lib/funciones.php"); 
    include("lib/conbd.php");
    valida_sesion();
    $con = conbd();
    ?>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- NAVEGACION -->
    <?php menu();?>
    <!-- /NAVIGATION -->

    <!--
    <!-- SECTION -->
    <div class="section" id="contenido">
        <!-- container -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- mesas -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                    <?php  

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mesas";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                        $total_mesas =0;
                        $total_mesas = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                        if($total_mesas>0){
                            echo '<div class="listar-mesas">';
                                for($r=0;$r<$total_mesas;$r++){
                                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                                     $idm =$row['0'];
                                     $desm =$row['1'];
                                     $numerom =$row['2'];
                                     $estadom =$row['3'];
                                     $ubim =$row['4'];
                                     //$_SESSION['mesa']=array("ID" => $idm,"DESCRIPCION" => $desm,"NUMERO" => $numerom,"ESTADO" => $estadom,"UBICACION" => $ubim);
                                    ?>
                                        <input id="btn-mesas" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $idm;?>">
                                        <label title="<?php echo $desm; ?>" for="btn-mesas"><a class="btn mesas"></a></label>
                                        <!--<a id="mesa"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $desm; ?>" value="<?php echo $idm; ?>" class="btn mesas"><?php echo $numerom; ?></a>-->


                                        <!--     
                                         <li><a href="" id="'.$idm.'">
                                                Mesa N° '.$numerom.' 
                                                <p class="text-muted">'.$desm.'</p>
                                              </a>
                                         </li>-->
                                         <?php
                                }


                            echo '</div>';
                        }else{
                                echo"no existen mesas";
                        }
                     ?>

                </div>
                <!-- /mesas -->
                <!--detalle - productos -->
               <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 ">
                 <!--detalle-->
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h3>Detalle</h3>
                       <form id="detalle" method="post">
                        <label>Mesa: </label><br>
                        <label>Personas: </label><br>
                        <table width="200" border="1" align="center">
                          <tr>
                            <td>QTY</td>
                            <td>Descripción</td>
                            <td>Peso</td>
                            <td>Precio</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>

                        </form>
                     </div>  
                 <!--/detalle-->
                 <!--Productos-->
                 <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                 <h3>Productos</h3>
                 <div class="listar-prod">
                    <?php  
                            //obtener productos para el menu
                            $sql_prod = "SELECT * FROM `productos";
                            $result_prod = mysqli_query($con,$sql_prod);
                            $total_prod =0;
                            $total_prod = mysqli_num_rows($result_prod);

                            if($total_prod>0){
                                    while($res=  mysqli_fetch_array($result_prod)){
                                        echo '
                                        <div class="prod">
                                            <a href=""><img src="'.$res["Productosimg"].'" width="100" heigth="100"><a>
                                        </div>
                                        ';
                                    }
                            }else{
                                    echo "no existen productos";
                            }
                        ?>
                     </div>

                 </div>
                 <!--/Productos-->
                </div>
              <!-- /detalle - productos -->
            </div>
            <!-- /row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /SECTION -->



    <footer>

        <!-- bottom footer -->
        <div id="bottom-footer" class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <ul class="footer-payments">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cc-visa"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cc-paypal"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cc-mastercard"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cc-discover"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cc-amex"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
                    <!-- /row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /bottom footer -->
    </footer>
    <!-- /FOOTER -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) { 

        $("#btn-mesas").each(function () {
             $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url:"pedidos/select_mesa.php",
             data:{busca: $("#btn-mesas").val()},
             dataType:"html",
             success: function(){
             alert("exito");
             }

            });
        })          
    });
```

Comment: Parece ser un [bug de jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3551). Puedes prescindir de jQuery para el uso de `querySelectorAll`, usando código Javascript puro.  O usa [la última versión de jQuery](https://code.jquery.com), quizá ya esté corregido. Aunque ese bug viene siendo reportado desde hace al menos 6 años y parece que no la han dado demasiada importancia

Comment: en efecto es un bug de jquery revisa aca sobre el mismo: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3551

Comment: No soy capaz de reproducir tu problema. ¿Podrías publicar el HTML completo (incluyendo la carga de jquery) generado por el PHP? Así nos evitamos tener que reproducir el comportamiento de tu script en PHP sin tener acceso a tu base de datos, etc. Si puedes, pásate por [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Gracias.

Comment: Estoy intentando reproducir tu problema. ¿Podrías decirme las versiones exactas de bootstrap, slick-carousel, font-awesome y nouislider? Estoy trabajando aquí en la reproducción: http://plnkr.co/edit/O7SuYQmjZGnvXoOBwVcn?p=preview

Comment: ¿Por qué en lugar de una versión local de jQuery, no usas la versión en línea, poniendo esto: **`<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`** en lugar de esto: `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Toda la razón, @A.Cedano , aunque yo recomendarían que lleven el [SRI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) por si las moscas. Además, estoy intentando reproducir el problema y a mí no me pasa. No sabemos qué navegador usa ni nada... voté el cierre de la pregunta por no poder reproducir el problema. Los "bugs" enlazados referencian a https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13881 y otros más que fueron cerrados con la etiqueta "not a bug", probablemente por activar en Explorer 10 la opción "parar en todas las excepciones" (incluso las capturadas).

Comment: @OscarGarcia interesante la observación sobre `SRI`, la cual desconocía. En cuanto al error, pude notar en efecto que en jQuery le dieron poca importancia, no lo consideraron como un bug (¿era quizá un problema aislado debido quizá a que esos usuarios tenían una copia local de jQuery?).

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de conseguir reproducir el problema, es un simple error a la hora de configurar el depurador de javascript. Si activas la opción de capturar todas las excepciones, incluso las capturadas, se detendrá la ejecución en los `assert` fallidos.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery usa una serie de `asserts` para hacer comprobaciones de compatibilidad y otras muchas cosas haciendo uso de la [siguiente función](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/32b00373b3f42e5cdcb709df53f3b08b7184a944/dist/jquery.js#L881):

```
function assert( fn ) {
    var el = document.createElement("fieldset");

    try {
        return !!fn( el );
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        // Remove from its parent by default
        if ( el.parentNode ) {
            el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
        }
        // release memory in IE
        el = null;
    }
}
```

El problema que sufres es que esta función provoca una excepción (que es capturada) para comprobar ciertas cosas del navegador o del comportamiento de javascript.

La [línea que te da error](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/32b00373b3f42e5cdcb709df53f3b08b7184a944/dist/jquery.js#L1316) hace uso de ese método, provocando una excepción que es capturada:

```
    assert(function( el ) {
        el.innerHTML = "<a href='' disabled='disabled'></a>" +
            "<select disabled='disabled'><option/></select>";

        // Support: Windows 8 Native Apps
        // The type and name attributes are restricted during .innerHTML assignment
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute( "type", "hidden" );
        el.appendChild( input ).setAttribute( "name", "D" );

        // Support: IE8
        // Enforce case-sensitivity of name attribute
        if ( el.querySelectorAll("[name=d]").length ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push( "name" + whitespace + "*[*^$|!~]?=" );
        }

        // FF 3.5 - :enabled/:disabled and hidden elements (hidden elements are still enabled)
        // IE8 throws error here and will not see later tests
        if ( el.querySelectorAll(":enabled").length !== 2 ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push( ":enabled", ":disabled" );
        }

        // Support: IE9-11+
        // IE's :disabled selector does not pick up the children of disabled fieldsets
        docElem.appendChild( el ).disabled = true;
        if ( el.querySelectorAll(":disabled").length !== 2 ) {
            rbuggyQSA.push( ":enabled", ":disabled" );
        }

        // Opera 10-11 does not throw on post-comma invalid pseudos
        el.querySelectorAll("*,:x");
        rbuggyQSA.push(",.*:");
    });
```

Ese código lo que hace es hacer una serie de comprobaciones contra el HTML definido en la parte superior.

Por cada comprobación que pudiera dar problemas se agrega una nueva regla a `rbuggyQSA`, y en el caso de la última línea no se ejecutará el `rbuggyQSA.push(",.*:");` si se genera la excepción.

Un truco inteligente para detectar si algo generaría una excepción, aunque se podría haber rodeado por un `try`/`catch` de manera equivalente:

```
try {
    // Opera 10-11 does not throw on post-comma invalid pseudos
    el.querySelectorAll("*,:x");
    rbuggyQSA.push(",.*:");
} catch (e) { /* no se agregará ",.*:" a rbuggyQSA */ }
```

---

La parada que sufres es debido a que tienes activada la detención de la ejecución del código javascript en caso de excepción incluso capturada.

Dependiendo del navegador usado el lugar donde puedes activar o desactivar dicha función en su consola de depuración es la siguiente:

- Google Chrome: en la pestaña "Sources" puedes encontrar la opción "Pause on exceptions" y "pause on caught exceptions".
- Internet Explorer 11 y Windows Edge: en la pestaña "Depurador", pulsando en el icono hexagonal la opción "Interrumpir en todas las excepciones" (se detiene en las capturadas, puede ser molesto) o "Interrumpir en excepciones no atendidas" (lo más recomendable).
- Firefox: en la pestaña "Depurador" tienes en la parte inferior del marco derecho la opción "Detenerse en excepciones" que tras marcarse puede activarse o desactivarse "Hacer una pausa en las excepciones capturadas".

Comment: Oscar ¿ *pause on caught exceptions*  se puede activar por programación ? ¿es recomendable hacerlo?

Comment: Si tu código no debería generar ni una excepción, entonces sería bueno activarlo, pero lo común es que se generen excepciones y se capturen y sólo depurar aquellas que no se capturaron y requieran modificar el código para actuar de una forma u otra cuando se produzca de nuevo esa excepción. Yo, personalmente, no lo recomendaría porque si una excepción es capturada es porque se esperaba dicha posibilidad y se actúa en consecuencia en el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias @OscarGarcia de todas formas el error ocurria con el navegador direfox 63.0.3 y google chrome 70.0.3538.110

Comment: No tengo un Firefox a mano para ver cómo desactivar esa opción en él. Mañana lo miro en el del trabajo y te digo cómo hacerlo.

Comment: @JohannSebastianPainevilLen , he editado mi respuesta para incluir la manera de activar o desactivar ese molesto comportamiento del depurador. Espero que soluciones tu problema desactivando la opción. Si no es así házmelo saber para investigar qué puede estar pasándote.