# ¿Qué significa integrity en la inclusión de esta librería? ¿Qué pasa si la omito?

Tags: jquery, seguridad

Hace tiempo me llamaba la atención de que al obtener el código para incluir la librería jQuery, aparece un atributo `integrity`:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Admito que muchas veces he omitido ese atributo, así como el atributo `crossorigin`, dado que si pongo el código así, funciona:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Me pregunto entonces, ¿qué significa `integrity` y qué ocurre si lo omito? (actualmente uso jQuery sin ese atributo y no sé si estoy corriendo algún riesgo).

¿Es algo propio de jQuery o existe en más librerías?

> **NOTA:** La pregunta surgió debido a [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217618/syntax-error-jquery-v3-1-1-el-queryselectorall-x-line-1317?noredirect=1#comment405202_217618) de @OscarGarcia en otra pregunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las versiones más modernas de los mejores navegadores incluyen una funcionalidad para que los sitios web puedan controlar cómo se carga su código JavaScript y así evitar que sea modificado por usuarios maliciosos.

Esta nueva funcionalidad, llamada "Integridad de Recursos" (en inglés, "SRI" o Subresource Integrity), permite a los sitios web incluir código JavaScript que no se ejecuta si su contenido ha sido modificado.

La gran ventaja que aporta es que puedes usar CDNs (Content Delivery Networks) para servir el contenido de tus sitios lo más rápido posible, pero al mismo tiempo asegurarte que los archivos no han sufrido ninguna modificación.

Usar la "integridad de recursos" es muy sencillo, tal y como muestra el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
integrity="sha384-R4/ztc4ZlRqWjqIuvf6RX5yb/v90qNGx6fS48N0tRxiGkqveZETq72KgDVJCp2TC"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

La idea consiste en añadir al elemento  una firma digital (en inglés, cryptographic hash) de sus contenidos. Cuando el navegador cargue la página, descargará los contenidos, calculará la firma digital y comprobará que su valor coincida con el del atributo integrity. Si no coinciden, el código JavaScript no se ejecuta. Por lo tanto, se trata de una medida de seguridad sencilla pero eficaz para protegerte frente a CDNs que han sido atacadas y frente a administradores de sistemas con malas intenciones.

La función utilizada para generar la firma digital debe ser lo suficientemente segura y resistente a las colisiones, de manera que cualquier mínimo cambio en el contenido genere una firma totalmente diferente y única.

Un detalle importante para utilizar esta funcionalidad es que la CDN debe soportar CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). Por eso en el ejemplo anterior se incluye el atributo crossorigin para forzar la activación de CORS al cargar los contenidos.

El valor anonymous del atributo crossorigin significa que el navegador debe ignorar cualquier cookie o información de autenticación que el usuario pueda tener asociado con ese dominio. Además de mejorar el rendimiento (al enviar menos información en la petición) esto impide que se filtre información entre diferentes dominios.

Todavía se está trabajando para ampliar esta funcionalidad a otros tipos de recursos diferentes a los archivos JavaScript. No obstante, ya puedes utilizarlo también para las hojas de estilos CSS. Simplemente añade al atributo integrity al elemento  de tus páginas

**RESUMEN:**

Sirve para verificar la integridad del archivo, si omitis el integrity podes usarlo de todas formas pero dejas la puerta abierta a que pueda ser modificado de forma maliciosa.

Fuente: https://librosweb.es/tutorial/como-evitar-que-tus-archivos-javascript-y-css-sean-manipulados/